# (Unix/Linux) How would I execute a C program from another C program that requires an input file?

Tags: c, exec

[image: terminal code]

In the picture above, the code can simply be run from the terminal. pipeclient and pipeserver files are run. pipeclient file takes command.txt as an input using the `<` symbol.

Now, if I don't want to run the pipeclient file from the terminal, but want to run from a C program, how would I go about it? Will the `exec` set of functions help me? How would I run the pipeclient file with the command.txt input file from a C program ?

Comment: on linux you can use popen()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The low-level way to run a program with input taken from a file is to:

- open the file for reading using `open`
- use the `dup2` system call to duplicate the open file handle over top of the handle for standard input (always handle `0`)
- `close` the old handle (the copy duplicated on top of handle `0` will stay open)
- use `execve` or another function from the `exec` family to switch to the new program, which will now have its standard input opened to the file.

This is the same way the shell itself implements the `< file` input redirection.

Here's an example that runs `/usr/bin/rev` using input from a `commands.txt` file in the current directory:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char **environ;

#define ERROR(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(1); } while(0)

int main()
{
    // open the input file
    int fd = open("commands.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        ERROR("open");

    // "dup" the handle to standard input (handle 0)
    if (dup2(fd, 0) == -1)
        ERROR("dup2");

    // close the old handle
    close(fd);

    // exec the program
    char *args[] = {"rev", NULL};
    execve("/usr/bin/rev", args, environ);

    // the program never gets here, unless the exec fails
    ERROR("execve");
    return -1;
}
```

You can also use the `system` command which executes a shell command including redirection, so the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ERROR(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(1); } while(0)

int main()
{
    if (system("/usr/bin/rev <commands.txt"))
        ERROR("system");

    // this *will* return after completion
    return 0;
}
```

will work as well.  Here, the `system` call is actually invoking a copy of a shell ("/bin/sh") to process the command line as if it was a shell command.

This is more convenient, but you have less control over the process of invoking the child program (e.g., setting up its environment, cleaning its argument list, etc.).  There are also complex potential security issues with using `system` that can be a problem if your program will run as `root`, though that may not be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `system` function to call your 2nd program for 1st c program.like

**1st.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    printf("I m 1st program");
    system("./2nd.out\n");
}
```

**2nd.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        printf("Hello there i m 2nd program\n")

}
```